# Chown on NFS mounted directory inside container: Operation not Permitted

Tags: permissions, docker, nfs

I've got an HDD that I partly want to use on my host (to backup VMs) as well as a TimeMachine backup disk inside a Docker container. Therefore I've created a ZFS dataset `tank1/storage/timemachine` that's mounted on `/storage/timemachine`. I've also shared this directory via NFS using `/etc/exports`:

`/storage/timemachine 172.16.0.3(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=101194)`

Inside my Docker **host** (172.16.0.3) I can mount `/storage/timemachine` and I can e.g. do `chown 101000 /storage/timemachine/test.txt` (executed as root). But inside a Docker **container** that has mounted /storage/timemachine (tried both as volume as bind mount) I cannot do a `chown 1000 test.txt` as I get a "Operation not permitted". I've also tried this with a non-NFS bind mount and than it works fine.

Is there something I can do to be able to use `chown` on NFS directories inside a Docker container? Or am I missing something?